# About malloc() and free() with dynamic pointer

Tags: c

My sub-major professor give me a question about dynamic pointer & change character!

He told me that I have to use `malloc(sizeof())` and `free()` also some pointers.

Please give me some hint you guys experienced!

I hope I wanna get some hints.... really.....

below code is hint code from professor. What should I do?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() {

int *num_ptr[3];
int size_ptr[3];
int i, num, j, tmp;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("input number!:  ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    size_ptr[i] = num;
    num_ptr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        printf("%d number! :", j + 1);
        scanf("%d", &tmp);
        *(num_ptr[i] + j) = tmp;
    }
}

printf("================ \n");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size_ptr[i]; j++) {
        printf("%d \t", *(num_ptr[i] + j));
    }
}
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        free(num_ptr[i]);
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vPX9.png)
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmokK.png)

Comment: What is your question? Also this code looks very odd, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know what you mean and I am on your side. But you have to admit that from point of view of OP there is a clear question: "What should I do?" Please explain more about what you want OP to do.

Comment: "*please give me some hint you guys experienced!*", You never mentioned *what* we have to give you a hint about and just pasted a block of text.

Comment: Kihyeon Kim Please show textual information in text form, instead of linking pictures of text.

Comment: We are happy to give you hints. It is part of the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions However, that compromise also requires you to do your part first. I already have a good hint readily phrased in my head. So if you spent some effort there will be a decent result for you.

Comment: @Ruks From the picture attached it looks like OP wants read in the strings instead of integers using same approach.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Not exactly. OPs teacher wants that, but OP does not realise it. That by the way is the first hint I had lined up. But there are more.... :-)

Comment: @Yunnosch His professor already gave him the hint, by providing working example for integer.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I'll try it again and get summarizing, then I ask again!

Comment: Some compilers won't let you through with `void main()` (I know [coliru won't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a2151ac1f9352d3))

Comment: The question basically is "How can I change this code so that my teacher is happy?"  As such, it is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

Use spaces in your includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The proper prototype for `main` is

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Always check the results of your calls:

```
for (int res = 0; res != 1;) // While bad input
{
    res = scanf("%d", &num);

    int c;

    /* Flush stdin */
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);        
}
```

and

```
num_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*num); // Don't cast malloc
if (num_ptr[i] == NULL)
{
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // Or whatever you want to do if malloc fails
}
```

prefer array notation

```
num_ptr[i][j]
```

it is clearer than

```
*(num_ptr[i] + j)
```

Finally, since `malloc` wants a `size_t` as size specifier, change the type:

```
size_t num;
```

and the format specifier

```
scanf("%zu", &num)
```

Comment: I do however agree with most of your proposed improvements.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine looks fine to me. About your question regarding `malloc()` and `free()` you are freeing all the memory you allocate, so, that is what you have to do.
My only further comment would be, you do not need to cast the return value from `malloc()`. You can then replace

```
num_ptr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
```

by

```
num_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
```

Comment: You missed the (well hidden) point of the question. The shown code is far from answering teachers question and improving it therefor does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok, I have to be honest I had to re-read the question several times and I agree this is not what he asked for. I will review my answer.

Comment: Good style. My respect for that. I will happily upvote for a good improvement (but after several hours of making money today...). Have fun.